# regex to tokenize sentences python

Tags: python, regex

I have a task to tokenize sentences like
`Python is good. C++ good as well.` to `Python is good.` and `C++ good as well.`

My algorithm is doing this, but when it's `Python is good.C++ good as well.` (no space after dot) it doesn't work. By the way I need to consider that `U.S.A.` is 1 sentence. So my consideration is tokenize only if it's `little character.BIG CHARACER`.

I'm using something like

```
re.sub(r"/([.!?])([A-ZА-Я])/g", "/$1 /$2", 'Python is good.C++ is great')
```

but that doesn't help me.

Comment: In short: don't. Use `nltk` instead.

Comment: Why are you using the Russian alphabet? `[А-Я]`

Comment: because this was test for russian words

Comment: What about "*I like the U.S.A.And Russia.*" ?

Comment: @yacc yes thats a problem

Comment: as suggested by @Jan ,  you should try `nltk` for generating tokens/keywords from your statements.

Comment: @SowjanyaRBhat it doesn't help with `Sentence1.Sentence2`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to normalize the "*old.New sentence*" occurrences to "*old. New sentence*" by inserting a space, and then applying `nltk`.

The regex to insert the space could be

```
re.sub(r"\.([A-Z][a-zA-Z+#]* )", r". \1", 'Python is good.C++ is great.C# also')
```

> 'Python is good. C++ is great. C# also'

Now this text can be fed into `nltk` to tokenize it into sentences:

```
nltk.sent_tokenize('Python is good. C++ is great. C# also')
```

> ['Python is good.', 'C++ is great.', 'C# also']

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use regexp to split sentences, the easiest is to match punctuation instead of sentences,

```py
>>> text = "Python is good. C++ is great. Another example: U.S.A."
>>> import re
>>> re.split('(?<=[!.?])', text)
['Python is good.', ' C++ is great.', ' Another example: U.', 'S.', 'A.', '']
```

this will not handle well all the edge cases though.

A better solution is to use either:

- [nltk](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#module-nltk.tokenize.punkt) which implements the unsupervised Punkt sentence tokenizer with a pretrained model for English
- [vtext](https://github.com/rth/vtext/) which tokenizes sentences based on the [Unicode Segmentation rules](https://unicode.org/reports/tr29/) (language independent),

```py
>>> from vtext.tokenize_sentence import UnicodeSentenceTokenizer
>>> tokenizer = UnicodeSentenceTokenizer()
>>> tokenizer.tokenize(text)
['Python is good. ', 'C++ is great. ', 'Another example: U.S.A.']
```